# File password extra protection

Tags: joomla-3.x, file-permissions, file-upload

We have a site which is used for files being uploaded and downloaded.

For added security we want to have it on set files when you click the link to download it you'll be requested a password, this is rather simple via the htaccess but we need these to be done via Joomla's admin.

Comment: try searching the Extensions directory: http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=file+download&q=download+password

Comment: Thank you for the link, I should have pointed out that I have looked at extensions.joomla.org and there was 1 item Password 2 download however this only does 10 links and not for Joomla 3.

Comment: you could possibly create another user group and only allow the files to be downloaded by this specific usergroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this extension might work. The code doesn't appear to be file based, it's folder based, but you might be able to make it work.

[QuickDownload](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/downloads/14306)